# Query syntax for nanoscale.io Store

Tags: javascript, store, microservices

Does anyone know how to use the query strings for accessing Store (collection) data in Nanoscale.io? I've tried to read their documentation but the only example is given below:

```
local.request = new AP.Store.Request();
local.request.select("Tasks", "priority >= $1 order numeric(priority) asc", parseInt(request.params.priority));
```

I don't know where the syntax in "priority >= $1 order numeric(priority) asc" is from...

In their docs:

> **select(collection, query)**
>
> Selects matching objects from a collection based off of the query
>   string.
>
> collection [string] - Collection name.
>
> query [string | number] - This can be either a query or a number. If a
>   number, the operation will return the object that has a matching ID.
>   To return all, use the string "true".

Apart from "true" I don't know how I can form my own queries.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided (and provided in the documentation), `priority` would be the field within your collection that you're interested in searching for and `$1` is the next value provided in the select function, i.e. `parseInt(request.params.priority)`. `request.params.priority` is the value of the query parameter "priority", which in this case is being parsed into an int for the sake of comparison.

From what I've found you can do the all the basic comparisons (`=`,`!=`,`>(=)`,`<(=)`).

Comment: I've edited your answer for formatting and to be entirely an answer.  Your question at the end belongs as a new question.  You can always link back to this post if you need context.  Otherwise, your answer seems to be helpful, and I would upvote your explanation if I were familiar with the technology and could verify that your information is correct.